# Why the code is not printing the "Came here" line?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=[1,2,3]
        def check():
            for value in self.a:
                yield value
        self.check_gen=check()
    
    def test(self):
        print("Came here")
        return self.check_gen.next()
a=A()
task_list=[a.test]
ans=filter(lambda x:not x(),task_list)
```

I am trying to understand why the print line is not getting printed. I am using python3.

Comment: when i am doing print(list(ans)) "came here" is getting printed. but shouldn't "came here" should be printed at that time of evaulating lambda x: not x() expression
AFAIK the filter function checks the task_list and iterates over element of it one by one in this case it calls the x and only inserts it if returns True. Am i missing something? @AndrejKesely

Comment: ```python3
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=[1,2,3]
        def check():
            for value in self.a:
                yield value
        self.check_gen=check()
    
    def test(self):
        print("Came here")
        # return self.check_gen.next()
a=A()
task_list=[a.test]
ans=filter(lambda x:not x(),task_list)
print([].extend(ans))
```

when i do this it first prints the "Came here" and then None. So, i want to understand when the code inside test() actually executes

Comment: Did you get that from a Python 2 book?

Comment: The question should be: I want to achieve X and how should I change this code? If you want that particular text to be printed, your code could be much simpler, but that is probably not your real goal

Answer (score 0):

Andrej Kesely is correct, but so is Hai Vu.

Apparently the `next` attribute has been removed/renamed to `__next__` for generators in newer python, I'm using 3.12.1.

HOWEVER, your code works fine, but you simply need to use the iterator before it starts printing. You don't even need to `print(list(ans))` like Andrej suggests. Simply `list(ans)` will run the print statement.

I made a simple test run just to test it out, but the filter object returned by filter does not actually run the functions until it is used. try uncommenting `list(test)` in my code to see it print an output

```
def print_return( user_string ):
    if user_string.upper() == user_string:
        print(f"{user_string}: Is upper")
        return True
    return False

str_arr = ['hello', 'HELLo', 'H', 'HELLO', 'NO', 'UES']
test =  filter(print_return, str_arr)
print(test)
# list(test)
```

Answer (score -1):

A few observations:

`self.check_gen` is an iterator and it does not have an attribute named `next`. Thus the expression `self.check_gen.next()` will generate the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

To fix this problem, you need to use the `next()` function:

```py
        return next(self.check_gen)
```

The heart of your problem is in this line:

```py
task_list=[a.test]
```

Here, `a.test` will return the method. I have a feeling that you want to call that function instead, by adding a pair of parentheses:

```py
task_list=[a.test()]
```

Overall, I don't know what you are trying to do so I cannot provide a suggestion. These are just my observations.